# Remove decimal value from pyspark column

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe column where there are mix of values like some are string and some are numbers like below -

```
Source_ids
abc_123
1234.0
345
abc_cad
K-123
540.0
456.0
```

I want to remove the decimal part wherever it is coming. So result should be

```
Source_ids
abc_123
1234
345
abc_cad
K-123
540
456
```

We can not make this column long type since it has text also. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `regexp_replace`. Replace `\..*$` with the empty string `''`.

This expression finds the `dot` and replaces everything after that.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("Source_ids", regexp_replace('Source_ids', '\..*$', '')).show()
```